# Twilio Studio HTTP Post Request Header

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am trying to use the Http Request Widget, content type - application/json.  I do not see an option to add a request header to supply a token.  This .Net code gets a success response:

```
        string str = "Hello Webservice";
        string url = "https://website.com/webserviceurl.php";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", "xxxx");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(str));
```

In Twilio Studio I tried setting the content type to form url encoded so that I could add my token as a parameter but that didn't work.  I got a 500 response.

Has anyone done this before?  I have reached out to Twilio support but thought I might get lucky here.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like I was not searching correctly as the answer is here:

[twilio studio does not allow headers in http requests if the body is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615925/twilio-studio-does-not-allow-headers-in-http-requests-if-the-body-is-json)